# Entering Xbox Live redeem codes online (rather than on Xbox 360 console)

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

Is there any way to enter those crazy 25-character alphanumeric Xbox Live redeem codes online instead of via Xbox 360 controller?

I have my XBL account linked with a Microsoft Passport account, if that helps....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can login to the [Xbox Marketplace](https://marketplace.xbox.com/) and redeem the code there. Click the "Redeem Code" link under "My Account."

Comment: If you have a USB keyboard around you can also plug that into your 360 and type that way.

Answer (score 5):

https://live.xbox.com/RedeemToken seems to be the current place to go.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the website tells you that you have to redeem a code on the console (this might be the case for all points codes from now on). If you have to do so, you can make the process a bit less painful by plugging in a standard USB keyboard.